# URL Structures (Listings & Pages)

Tags: structure, url

I'm working on a site that has an 'edition', like a newspaper. The URL structure looks like this:

```
website.dev/edition/2013-05-01
```

The date is the name and url title of the listing.

The edition channel links to all the content added to the website: articles, images, video, etc which all have their own listing channels. I'm using the structure module by the way.

If I view an article from an edition the url structure is like:

```
website.dev/article/the-name-of-the-article
```

If I make the other listing channels subpages of the editions, the url structure will look like this:

```
website.dev/edition/article/the-name-of-the-article
```

Basically I want it to look like this:

```
website.dev/edition/2013-05-01/article/the-name-of-the-article
```

Any advice on how to do this (Using the structure module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm, sounds like a job for [Router](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/router).

Comment: I've never seen this before, thanks for the link. I've found a free alternative using Freebie.

Answer (score 1):

With Structure, every segment must be a page in the hierarchy. You may be able to do what you're looking for utilizing Freebie though: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freebie

Comment: Great, thanks! Was curious if there was a way to do it in Structure. I've used Freebie and will try a solution with that.